# Nest.js empty Body for form data

Tags: javascript, express, nestjs

I have a simple controller, in this controller I have this endpoint

```
@Post('/temp')
async asdf(
  @Body() form: Record<string, string>,
  @Res({ passthrough: true }) response: Response,
) {
  this.logger.debug(JSON.stringify(form));
  await response.json({ ok: true, form: JSON.stringify(form) });
}
```

When I try to POST some form data on it, using cURL or the browser, the object `form` is empty.

Example:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:4000/mycontroller/temp -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "param1=value1&param2=value2"
```

Results in

> {"ok":true,"form":"{}"}

Other controllers work; I can't see any difference between my controller and the endpoint to others.

What I'm doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Have you tried setting the header to `Content-Type: application/json` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ?

Comment: I need to get this work with form data, not JSON.

Comment: The you have to find another way to access the data. AFAIK the @Body() decorator expects json-data. Maybe try @Param() or @Query().

Comment: Other controllers use @Body for form data, which is very strange.

Comment: You're passing the data encoded in the URL. @Body() looks in the body property of the request (req.body). But this property is empty. The data is in the URL. I'm not certain, but you could be able to access this data with one of the other decorator functions, as they look for the data in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using form data you need to implement a form data parser, like busboy or `multer`. Nest integrates with `multer` and `express` already via the `FileInterceptor` and its variants. This will force `multer` to parse the request. If you don't use any files, just the form data format, I believe there is a `NoFileInterceptor` or similar.

---

Looks like there is no `NoFileInterceptor`. You could use `AnyFileInterceptor` instead and ignore the `req.files`, just be aware it could end up having your server taken down if a really nasty set of files comes in for multer to parse

Comment: I'll accept your answer, however, for me, what solved was adding `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`

Comment: Ah, good to mention that that makes it parse `form-data` as well. It might end up interfering with file uploads if you ever do that, so just be aware of the possibility